# Link to pop of version of gmail message with javascript

Tags: javascript, gmail

I'm working on integrating gmail into an in house application so on a users dashboard they see the 10 newest emails with in their gmail account. I'm pulling in the emails using fsockopen and issue imap commands.

I've gotten the url to direct link to the message that looks something like this: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/13e2b4235af0b71a

However in a pop up that still contains all of gmails regular interface. What I'd like to be able to do is from the link in our system pop up the gmail pop up version (if you click the "in new window" button within gmail). See below for the gmail pop up I'd like to direct link to.

edit: For those wondering. No grabbing the url from the bar and changing the thread id (th=) doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to achieve. What is wrong about replacing https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/13e2b4235af0b71a with https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&view=btop&search=inbox&th=13e2b4235af0b71a if you have the thread ID or using a simple regexp?

Comment: That link doesn't work unless clicked from within gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Building it like this makes the application very dependent of Google. If they decide to work something else out as it works faster you need to rethink your hack.
I'd strongly recommend to use a more Generic approach.

Either using the GMAiL API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/
Or using SMTP/IMAP/POP commands to the GMail server.

Good Luck!